# AS3 Slider Component: How to convert one range to another?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a AS3 slider, that has a min-max range of 0 to 100

I need to move a 3D model, when the slider changes.

. when the slider value = 0, the 3D model must have the angle (-)45°

. when the slider value = 50, the 3D model must have the angle 0°

. when the slider value = 100, the 3D model must have the angle 45°.

(And of course all values in the midle)

Which equation I must use to convert the values and get this result?

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - is there any reason you can't just set the slider range to -45 to +45?  Check out Slider.minimum and Slider.maximum in the AS3 documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`((sliderValue / 100) * 90) - 45`

This way, you're getting the ratio of the slider value to the range. You apply that ratio to the total range of the -45 to 45 (90), then subtract the 45 to offset the fact that your starting point is -45.